# How do you move non-zero elements in an array to the top in a single cycle?

Tags: verilog

I have the following 8-bit array:

```
0
4
0
0
5
0
2
0
```

How do I make it to the following in a single cycle (without iterating the element one by one)?

```
4
5
2
0
0
0
0
0
```

I know how to do it in software (MATLAB), but I'm not sure how to do it with combinational logic.

```
% initialise temporary vectors
TempType = zeros(maxType,1);
TempStart = zeros(maxType,1);
TempStop = zeros(maxType,1);
index = 1;

% remove zero elements from the middle
for j = 1:maxType
    if (PreType(j) > 0 && PreStart(j) > 0 && PreStop(j) > 0)
        TempType(index) = PreType(j);
        TempStart(index) = PreStart(j);
        TempStop(index) = PreStop(j);
        index = index + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: @Greg It's not homework. I'm trying to implement an algorithm I wrote on MATLAB to RTL. On MATLAB it's trivial because of how it handles arrays but I'm not sure how to do it on hardware. I know how to do it by iteration but it takes a large number of cycles for very long sequences, so I'm trying to see if it can be done using combinational logic.

Comment: How deep can your array get?  I can think of a way to do it but it would start to chew up hardware resources pretty quickly if your arrays are deep. If your array depth is N, it would require N N-to-1 muxes.

Comment: @Ciano Up to 512, though 256 is acceptable if 512 is too big. It needs to be synthesized on an FPGA, but at the moment I'm happy just being able to simulate it on ModelSim.

Comment: I don't think a single cycle implementation is a good idea for a large array like that, that's far too much logic to pack into a single combinational path. Also if you have a large number of integers, you would likely store them in a ram of some sort, meaning that you would only be able to read one or two entries per cycle.

Comment: What `Verilog` have you tried and what is the array? A 1D memory of 8bit integers 32 bit?. How do you plan on storing all this data? RAM, you can probably only access 2 values per clock cycle. Flip-flops 256x32 bits => 8192 accessed in 1 clock cycle. Your clock does not have to run at your data rate, have you thought about over clocking it?

Comment: You should probably research for something like Digital Hardware sorting. In particular [Bitonic Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter), [Batcher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort) and [Pairwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_sorting_network). Which are listed under Wikipedia's concurrent sorts.

Comment: 1 - what is an '8-bit array' (is it eight 8-bit integers?); 2 - how long is your cycle, 3 - how much hardware can you use?

Comment: @Morgan each element is 3 bit in size.

Comment: @EML 8 bit was just an example. The actual code uses up to 512 arrays containing 3 bits each. I have no idea how long is my cycle since I haven't done a complete simulation run yet, but the frequency is probably somewhat less than the 50mhz provided by an FPGA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think any simplified sorting algorithm can do the job. For example, here is a modified bubble sort solution implemented in a single cycle:

```
module MoveZeros;
  parameter W1 = 8;
  parameter W2 = 10;
  integer i, j;
  logic [W1-1:0] array[W2-1:0] = {0,4,0,0,5,0,2,0,0,1};
  logic [W1-1:0] temp;


  always_comb begin
    for (i=W2-1 ; i >=0 ; i=i-1)
      for (j=W2-1 ; j >= 0 ; j=j-1)
    begin

      if (array[j]==0 && array[j-1] != 0) begin
        temp = array[j];
        array[j] = array [j-1];
        array[j-1] = temp;          
      end
    end
  end

endmodule


output:
# array = '{4, 5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Working example on [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Sj). Depending on your cycle time and the width of your input array (W2), you may want to break this algorithm into multiple cycles.

Synthesis tools unroll loops, therefore, the synthesized circuit will have O(W2^2) comparators and multiplexers, which can explode. Hence for bigger arrays, a multi-cycle solution is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not familiar with O notation. Let's say W2 = 8. Does that mean 64 comparators and 64 multiplexers will be synthesized?

Comment: @geft: Big Oh notation is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. A simple implementation of each iteration requires two comparators, which compare array[j] and array[j-1] with 0 and one crossbar for swapping them (which can be implemented with mux's). So I would say 128 mux's and 128 comparators.

Comment: Sorting Networks can be used to implement a sorting algorithm in hardware too. See, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182490/comparing-numbers-to-sort-then-get-median-value and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, which would take several hours of work, but SO's comments are not up to this sort of question. You should ask on comp.arch.fpga, if it's still alive.

Start by finding a datasheet for one of the old asynchronous fall-through FIFOs; these will include a circuit diagram. You don't really want to do anything like this, because the stage-to-stage handshaking is hairy, and you can't apply all 8 values simultaneously, but it'll give you ideas for a more synchronous implementation. Adapting a fall-through FIFO to do what you want is trivial - just ignore zero inputs.

If you can go up to 8 clock cycles, a more synchronous implementation is easy, with relatively limited hardware.

One cycle doesn't look too difficult, but will use more hardware. How sure are you that you must do it in one cycle? How much hardware can you use? If you've got a free PLL/DLL I'd be inclined to use that to get an 8x clock.

*EDIT*

Actually, with the benefit of more than 2 minutes thought, this seems pretty easy, even in one cycle.

Say you've got 8 registers with your 8 inputs (I0-I7), and 8 output registers (Q0-Q7). Each output register has associated logic which selects an input register for source data. The Q0 selector finds the lowest-numbered I register which contains non-zero data. The Q1 selector finds the next highest I register which contains non-zero data, and so on. Each selector drives a mux which loads the corresponding output register. Q0 requires an 8-1 mux (eight 8-bit inputs from I0-I7, one 8-bit output which goes to the input of Q0). Q1 requires a 7-1 mux (the inputs can only be I1-I7), and so on, until Q7, which doesn't require a mux at all (it can only be driven by I7).

The only smarts are in the selectors which find the source data for each output register. The Q7 selector is trivial; Q7 can only select I7, and only if all of I0-I7 contain non-zero data. Q6 is a bit more complicated, and so on.

If you can't see how to code a selector, ask specifically about that one in a new question, to avoid all the comments.

Comment: Well, it doesn't absolutely have to be one cycle. I was just wondering if it's possible (and practical) . I guess sequential logic is the way to go then. I'm relatively new to verilog and I was curious as to how this is normally accomplished in hardware.

Comment: 'seems pretty easy' Not sure I agree, especially with 512 registers instead of 8, While your solution would stay the same the selection logic sounds like it would blow up to something huge.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that before the new 512 x 3-bit registers comment. It's not really practical for 512 registers. @geft: you need to look at the system first - how you get the 512 input registers loaded, whether they actually *are* registers or whether you've got a FIFO/RAM, how long it takes to get the data in, how you get the data out, and so on. This will give you the number of clock cycles you've got to do the processing.